# How to monitor free space on Kubernetes persistent volumes

Tags: kubernetes

Since the persistent volume information was removed from the kubelets metric information. What is the best method of monitoring or checking free space on persistent volumes?

Answer (score 2):

[Node-exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) exports the space usage of all the machine's filesystems (both the boot disk and all the currently attached persistent volumes). It works great.